# Displaying a list of paired bluetooth devices in a popup dialog - setAdapter null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to create a simple app that displays a list of paired bluetooth devices in a dialog box when a "Connect" item in the action bar is clicked. Here is the XML of the dialog I'm inflating:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bt_list"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/BTList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the relevant portion of MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    TextView statusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDeviceID);

    myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (myBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        statusText.setText("Bluetooth not supported on this phone");
    }
    else {
        statusText.setText("Waiting to connect");
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.connect) {
        if (!myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent turnOnIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnOnIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        showBTDialog();
    }

    else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_settings) {
        // TODO
    }

    return true;
}

public void showBTDialog() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View Viewlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bt_list, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.bt_list));

    popDialog.setTitle("Paired Bluetooth Devices");
    popDialog.setView(Viewlayout);

    // create the arrayAdapter that contains the BTDevices, and set it to a ListView
    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.BTList);
    BTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    myListView.setAdapter(BTArrayAdapter);

    // get paired devices
    pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    // put it's one to the adapter
    for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName()+ "\n" + device.getAddress());

    // Button OK
    popDialog.setPositiveButton("Pair",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            });

    // Create popup and show
    popDialog.create();
    popDialog.show();

}
```

But when I run this on the phone, the app crashes and the stack trace shows a null pointer exception at:

```
myListView.setAdapter(BTArrayAdapter);
```

When I comment out the line above, the "Connect" button displays a blank dialog popup as it should. I think the crash something to do with "BTList" not being in the context of the current view, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get your ListView from your inflated layout `ViewLayout` in `showBTDialog` like that:

```
myListView = (ListView) ViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.BTList);
```

Or isn't this what you wanted to do?

Comment: I see. That makes a lot of sense now. Thank you.